# Can i convert whole cakephp website to web services?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hey I m working on project in cakephp. There will also be apps for Android as well as iPhone. How can i convert my web code to web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There is a way to convert complete site in web-services of any version of cakephp.

There is step to follow:
 1. Put "Router::parseExtensions("pdf", "json");" this line to your routes.php in config folder before routing rules.
 2. Overwrite your "beforeRender" and "Redirect" function in AppController with following:

```
    function beforeRender() {
        if (Configure::read("debug") == 0) {
          if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {
            $this->layout = "error";
          }
        } else {
          if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {
            $this->layout = "error";
          }
        }

        if ($this->params["ext"] == "json") {

          $paging = $requests = "";

          if (isset($this->params["paging"]) && !empty($this->params["paging"])) {
            $paging = $this->params["paging"];
          }
          $this->set(compact("paging"));

          if (isset($this->request->data) && !empty($this->request->data)) {
            $requests = $this->request->data;
          }
          $this->set(compact("requests"));

          if ($this->Session->check("Message.flash") && is_array($this->Session->read("Message.flash"))) {
            foreach ($this->Session->read("Message.flash") as $key => $value) {
              $this->set($key, $value);
            }
          }
          if (isset($this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors) && !empty($this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors)) {
            $this->set("formError", $this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors);
          }

          if (isset($this->viewVars["params"])) {
            unset($this->viewVars["params"]);
          }
          if (isset($this->viewVars["request"])) {
            unset($this->viewVars["request"]);
          }
          $response = $this->viewVars;

          if (!in_array($this->params["action"], $this->Auth->allowedActions) && !$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            $response = array("authError" => true, "message" => "Please login to access.");
          }
          $this->set(compact("response"));
          $this->set('_serialize', array("response"));
        }
      }

      public function redirect($url, $status = NULL, $exit = true) {
        if ($this->params["ext"] == "json") {

          $paging = $requests = "";

          if (isset($this->params["paging"]) && !empty($this->params["paging"])) {
            $paging = $this->params["paging"];
          }
          $this->set(compact("paging"));

          if (isset($this->request->data) && !empty($this->request->data)) {
            $requests = $this->request->data;
          }
          $this->set(compact("requests"));

          if (isset($this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors) && !empty($this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors)) {
            $this->set("formError", $this->{$this->modelClass}->validationErrors);
          }
          if (!in_array($this->params["action"], $this->Auth->allowedActions) && !$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            $response = array("authError" => true, "message" => "Please login to access.");
          }
          $this->set(compact("response"));
          $this->set('_serialize', array("response"));
        } else {
          parent::redirect($url, $status = NULL, $exit = true);
        }
      }
```

Note: If you are checking for Ajax request using that request is ajax or not, and you want to response to your ajax, you have to put your response in "IF" condition

```
if (!isset($this->params["ext"])) {
           // echo json_encode($response);
           // echo "success";
           // die; 
        }
```

Otherwise you can render your view in response.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

You basically need to modify your routes. You also need to modify (serialize) what your controllers return.